# SQL Update with Multiple updates per Record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update months of a given persons records to reduce their potential if they get a claim within a month.

```
UPDATE M 
SET POTENTIAL_HITS = POTENTIAL_HITS - 1  
FROM #TEMP_CDC_MEMBERS M 
INNER JOIN #TEMP_CDC_CLAIMS C ON M.CIN = C.CIN AND C.MEASURE_INDICATOR = M.SUB_MEASURE
WHERE M.MOE > C.MOE
```

The MOE is a month field in a **201607** format.

The problem I am having is if there is a hit in one month, that difference will be ignored in a later month (due to SQL transactions).

Is there a way to update the potential without using a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `update` doesn't do cumulative updates -- only one update per record in `m`.  I think you can do what you want using `cross apply`:

```
UPDATE M 
SET POTENTIAL_HITS = POTENTIAL_HITS - c.cnt
FROM #TEMP_CDC_MEMBERS M CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM #TEMP_CDC_CLAIMS C 
      WHERE M.CIN = C.CIN AND C.MEASURE_INDICATOR = M.SUB_MEASURE AND M.MOE > C.MOE) c;
```

Comment: Thanks - that was just what I was looking for (and without asking for sample data).